# MySQL TimeStamp to Excel Date/ Time

Tags: mysql, excel, datetime

I have CSV file imported form MySQL database. The date column in the file is in MySQL timestamp format e.g. **"2014-11-17 04:58:28 +00:00"**.
I need to convert it in to Excel date format i.e. **"mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"**. I have tired all available 'Cell Format' options, Linux timestamp to date conversion but none worked. I don't have access to DB and number of rows are more than 2000 (manual conversion would be the last resort :( ).

**Q:** What is this +00:00 part for?
**Q:** There must be some conversion formula as I know this is a popular date format of MySQL.

Comment: Which tool to do use to import the CSV to MySQL database? In old sayings, *Garbage In, Garbage Out* you've the obligation to clean up the data format before import. Using PHP is 1 way.

Comment: checkout mysql `date_format()` function

Comment: @Raptor as mentioned, I don't have access to MySQL data (original Data) or option to get a reimport with desired formats. I have to deal with data as is..

Comment: But you can adjust the CSV first. Clean up to desired format & escape any data if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Truncating +00:00 left me with convertible date data.

```
=TEXT(LEFT(DATE_FILED,19),"MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS")
```

The first Part: **LEFT(DATE_FILED,19)** truncated the +00:00 part off
Then TEXT() converted to date to required format!

Comment: This works only if all dates are `+00:00`, or the timezone information will be lost.

Comment: Firstly, all my data is with +00:00 timezone, Secondly I have came up with no other option but to truncate additional info..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way that the data is stored on MySQL server. The format in which they are stored uses +00:00 to show the timezone in which this time is. Therefore, if the time was not in UTC, then you can convert it to UTC using the value after "+" (plus) sign.

I am not aware how you can delete this, unless you create a macro that will add the value after "+" to the time, so you are certain there is not an error regarding timezones.

Hope I helped, sorry for not finding an actual solution.

**EDIT**

Your solution only works if the timezone is always +00:00. Otherwise you have to use a macro to ensure correct timestamp.